# jQuery - .off() this

Tags: jquery

I have one map that changes it coordonated, name and id, dinamically with ajax $.post:

```
<map name="diffmap1" id="diffmap1">
<area  shape="poly" coords="76,269,50,243,51,221,82,255" class="diff diff1" onFocus="blur();" >
<area shape="poly" coords="152,347,253,292,264,307,167,358" class="diff diff2" onFocus="blur();" >
<area shape="poly" coords="93,244,164,215,171,233,97,264" class="diff diff3" onFocus="blur();" >
</map>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.diff', function () {
e.preventDefault();
$(document).off('mousedown', $(this));
});
```

Ajax response:

```
$('map').attr('name', 'diffmap'+response.next).attr('id', 'diffmap'+response.next);
$('#diffmap'+response.next+' .diff3').attr('coords', response.nextcoord[0]);
$('#diffmap'+response.next+' .diff1').attr('coords', response.nextcoord[1]);
$('#diffmap'+response.next+' .diff2').attr('coords', response.nextcoord[2]);
```

I want when I click on one coordonate to unbind it, so you are able to click only once, and than when I go the the next level and the ajax changes the coordonates to be able again to click them.

If I use:

```
 $(document).off('mousedown', $(this));
```

it doesn't work, or if I use

```
 $(document).off('mousedown', '.diff');
```

than it will unbind all the coordonates when I click one of them.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't turn off a single element when using delegation. What I suggest you is to use a `data`, just like that :

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.diff', function () {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).data('__off') !== true){
         $(this).data('__off', true);
         //Your function here.
    }
 });
```

Comment: It's working, but when I go to the next level I can't click on new inserted coordonates (by ajax) anymore.

Comment: @MarinescuEdward After your ajax complet, add `$('.diff').data('__off', false);`

Comment: It's working, even if I didn't understand the .data() stuff , thanks a lot.

Comment: `data` is a variable that is bind to the DOM element, hence `this`!

Answer (score 0):

You can add/remove a class to enable/disable mousedown for example:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.diff', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass("diff");
});
```